# Making PHP Functions work with one another

Tags: php, html, function

I am building a webpage which enables the users to view a report on a certain product they have chosen. The steps are as follows:

`User chooses interface` (Beta or Cloud) -> `User Chooses Product` (Products are based off of interface chosen.)-> Info is displayed accordingly.

The page where the info is displayed is written as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="roundiv" >

        <h4>*Interface: </h4>
        <select class="form-control " style='width:250px;' onclick="INSERT SOMETHING HERE" >
            <option value="-1"  >Select Interface </option>
            <?php
                config::selectInterface($cao);
            ?>

        </select>

        <h4>
            *Product:
        </h4>
        <select class="form-control" style="width:250px;">
            <option value="-1" >Select Product</option>
            <?php
                config::selectIntProduct($cao);
            ?>
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-success " value="Submit" onclick="" style="margin-left: auto; display:block;"  > Submit </button>
        <!-------------INFO WILL BE DISPLAYED HERE------------->
    </div>
```

I have started writing functions in the config class and want to keep with this approach.

This is the function I wrote in the config class:

FUNCTION 1

```
public static function selectInterface(CGenDb $cao) {

    $sel_interface_options = new CGenRS("select type_desc, type_id from lu_type where type_status = 't' and type_group = 'cloud' and type_sub_group = 'db'", $cao);
    $sel_interface_options->first();
    if ($sel_interface_options->rowcount()) {
        while (!$sel_interface_options->eof()) {
            echo "<option value='" . $sel_interface_options->valueof('type_id') . "'>" . $sel_interface_options->valueof('type_desc') . "</option>";
            $sel_interface_options->next();
        }
    }
    $interface_bool = True;
    return $interface_bool;
}
```

And the class `selectIntProducts` would look something like this:

FUNCTION 2

```
public static function selectIntProduct(CGendb $cao,$selected_interface){

    $selected_interface=$cao_interface= "The interface ID"

    $sel_product_options = new CGenRS("select prod_name, prod_id from lu_products where prod_active = 't'", $cao_interface);
    $sel_product_options->first();

            if ($sel_product_options->rowcount()) {
                while (!$sel_product_options->eof()) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $sel_product_options->valueof('prod_id') . "'>" . $sel_product_options->valueof('prod_name') . "</option>";
                    $sel_product_options->next();
                }
            }
}
```

This is what I however need help with:

1. I want to display the product picker only if an interface is/was selected.(My idea was to return the `$interface_bool` from function 1,test if it is true and if it is, display the next section.)
2. The value chosen in function 1 should then be the `$selected_interface` in function 2

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve it with php, when you reload the page and send the selected interface back to php.

Better and more convenient would be to use javascript for populating the selects and for that I would suggest using [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/). It has quite good documentation to follow.

For php, I would suggest this:

```
<div class="roundiv" >
    <h4>*Interface: </h4>
    <select class="form-control " style='width:250px;' onchange="document.location.href='https://url-to-same-page&interface=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" >
        <option value="-1"  >Select Interface </option>
        <?php
            config::selectInterface($cao, $_GET['interface']);
        ?>

    </select>

<?php if (!empty($_GET['interface'])): ?>
    <h4>
        *Product:
    </h4>
    <select class="form-control" style="width:250px;">
        <option value="-1" >Select Product</option>
        <?php
            config::selectIntProduct($cao, $_GET['interface']);
        ?>
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-success " value="Submit" onclick="" style="margin-left: auto; display:block;"  > Submit </button>
    <!-------------INFO WILL BE DISPLAYED HERE------------->

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

and also update `selectInterface` to include selected interface:

```
public static function selectInterface(CGenDb $cao, $selected_interface) {
    // ... code
    while (!$sel_interface_options->eof()) {
        echo "<option value='" . $sel_interface_options->valueof('type_id') . "' "
             . ($selected_interface == $sel_interface_options->valueof('type_id') ? 'selected="selected"' : '')
             . ">" . $sel_interface_options->valueof('type_desc') . "</option>";
        $sel_interface_options->next();
    }
    // .. code continues
}
```